# How to practically define a lot of things based on a condition in Scheme/Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm working in Racket but as far as I know this is the case in Scheme in general; you cannot do something like this because we are trying to define something in an expression context:

```
(if condition
    (define x "do a backflip")
    (define x "do a barrel roll"))
```

Now for this particular case I could do something like this instead:

```
(define x
  (if condition
      "do a backflip"
      "do a barrel roll"))
```

But if you have a lot of different things to define this gets really awful, because instead of

```
(if condition
    (begin (define x "do a backflip")
           (define y "awesome")
           (define z "shoot me"))
    (begin (define x "do a barrel roll")
           (define y "nice")
           (define z "give me sweet release")))
```

we get

```
(define x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  (if condition
      "do a backflip"
      "do a barrel roll"))
(define y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  (if condition
      "awesome"
      "nice"))
(define z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  (if condition
      "shoot me"
      "give me sweet release"))
```

Which isn't as DRY as it could be, we are constantly repeating the test for `condition`. And the result is that if instead of testing for `condition` we want to check for `other-condition`, we have to make changes `n` times for `n` the amount of things being defined. Is there a better way to do this, and if so: How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `define-values`:

```
(define-values (x y z) (if condition
                           (values "do a backflip"    "awesome" "shoot me")
                           (values "do a barrel roll" "nice"    "give me sweet release")))
```

Answer (score 4):

If "a lot" is really large, you might want to use Racket's [`units`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mzlib_unit.html).

First define a *signature* with all the variables you want to define:

```
(define-signature acro^ (x y z))
```

Then define *units* that contain the different sets of definitions:

```
(define-unit flippy@
  (import) (export acro^)
  (define x "do a backflip")
  (define y "awesome")
  (define z "shoot me"))

(define-unit rolly@
  (import) (export acro^)
  (define x "do a barrel roll")
  (define y "nice")
  (define z "give me sweet release"))
```

You can choose dynamically which unit do *invoke* and bind to the names in the signature:

```
(define-values/invoke-unit
  (if .... flippy@ rolly@)
  (import) (export acro^))

x
;; => either "do a backflip" or "do a barrel roll", depending on condition
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over `define-values`?